# find xpath to pick following sibling not after another tag same as current in xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I would like to get the following sibling C when I'm matching A or A1 template in the following, for the second A or A1 only:

```
<root>
  <A/>  <!-- first A -->
  <B/>
  <A/>  <!-- second A -->
  <C/>
  <A1/>
  <B/>
  <A1/>
  <B/>
  <C/>
</root>
```

- If I'm matching the first A, I have not to retrieve anything as there is another A before my C tag.
- If I'm matching the second A, I have to retrieve the C tag.

I tried the following without success:

```
 <xsl:template match="A|A1">
     <xsl:if test="following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A|A1[1] = .]">
```

It seems to be true in every case but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you could use a test like

```
following-sibling::C[
    (preceding-sibling::A|preceding-sibling::A1)[last()] is current()]
```

to find all the Cs whose nearest preceding `A` or `A1` is the one you first thought of.  For XSLT 1.0 you'd have to compare `generate-id` values instead of using `is`

```
following-sibling::C[
     generate-id((preceding-sibling::A|preceding-sibling::A1)[last()])
   = generate-id(current())]
```

This would select

```
<root>
  <A/>  <!-- nothing -->
  <B/>
  <A/>  <!-- C1 -->
  <C/>  <!-- this is C1 -->
  <A1/> <!-- nothing -->
  <B/>
  <A1/> <!-- C2 -->
  <B/>
  <C/>  <!-- this is C2 -->
</root>
```

---

Your original test

```
following-sibling::C[preceding-sibling::A|A1[1] = .]
```

is equivalent to

```
following-sibling::C[
  ( preceding-sibling::A | (child::A1[1]) ) = .]
```

and would select all following `C` siblings for whom either (a) *any* of their preceding `A` siblings or (b) their first `A1` child has a string value the same as that of the `C` itself.  All the `C` elements in your document satisfy this predicate as every element has the empty string value.

Comment: thanks for your answer. another question: you've written "preceding-sibling::A|preceding-sibling::A1" instead of "preceding-sibling::A|A1", is this a point too ?

Comment: @skoll yes, `|` is an operator between path expressions, `::` is part of a single location step, so `preceding-sibling::A|A1[1]` means `(preceding-sibling::A)|(A1[1])`.