# xsl / xpath to select siblings up to, but not next similar sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my first post at StackExchange, so bear with me if I am doing something wrong:

I have an XML file that is derived from a product database, and where all grouping information is lost, except the order of the elements. All products have an article number element that comes first, followed by an unknown number of other elements, until next product begins with a new article number element, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Envelope>
    <body>
        <products>
            <ARTNO>10-0001</ARTNO>
            <LEVARTNO>K01-300</LEVARTNO>
            <EAN></EAN>
            <WEBGRUPP1>200</WEBGRUPP1>
            <ARTNO>10C0414</ARTNO>
            <LEVARTNO>0505-0906</LEVARTNO>
            <EAN></EAN>
            <WEBGRUPP1>701</WEBGRUPP1>
            <WEBGRUPP2></WEBGRUPP2>
        </products>
    </body>
</Envelope>
```

I would need to restructure that to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Envelope>
    <body>
        <products>
            <Product>
                <ARTNO>10-0001</ARTNO>
                <LEVARTNO>K01-300</LEVARTNO>
                <EAN></EAN>
                <WEBGRUPP1>200</WEBGRUPP1>
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <ARTNO>10C0414</ARTNO>
                <LEVARTNO>0505-0906</LEVARTNO>
                <EAN></EAN>
                <WEBGRUPP1>701</WEBGRUPP1>
                <WEBGRUPP2></WEBGRUPP2>
            </Product>
        </products>
    </body>
</Envelope>
```

I have been trying for several hours to find a solution that I can understand, but haven't been able to do so, so far. I have found a very similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682712/find-xpath-to-pick-following-sibling-not-after-another-tag-same-as-current-in-xs) but since I need to match other (unknown) elements except the ARTNO my attempts to apply it to my case has not worked out.

My very simple XSL (XSL 1) is based on my assumption that one should be able to get all following siblings UP TO the next ARTNO element, but then nothing more (the Test element is just while trying things out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" name="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <Products>
                <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/body/products/*">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Products>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ARTNO">
        <Product>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <Test>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ARTNO[1]"/>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[not(self::ARTNO)][2]"/> -->
            </Test>
        </Product>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I suppose I could do something really ugly, loop the entire structure, and by using position etc solve it, but as I am sure there are far better approaches I hope that some XSLT wizard can provide some guidance. That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One comment - if your processor is XSLT 1.0 then you should say `version="1.0"` rather than `version="1.1"`, as any version greater than 1.0 will enable ["forwards compatible" mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards) which can suppress some useful bits of error checking.

Comment: Thanks Ian, that is a good advice, which I intend to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this problem becomes very easy using `<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="ARTNO"/>`. So switch to XSLT 2.0 if you can.

In XSLT 1.0 my preferred approach is "sibling recursion". Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="products">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ARTNO"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ARTNO">
  <product>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="copy-siblings"/>
  </product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-siblings">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="copy-siblings"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ARTNO" mode="copy-siblings"/>
```

The idea is that when you're processing an ARTNO or one of its following siblings, you call a template that copies that element and then moves on to the next sibling; and when you get to another ARTNO, you do nothing, which terminates the recursion.

Comment: Thanks Michael (I am a great fan of yours :-) Your example worked perfectly, aside from a small typo at <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-siblings"/>, which should of course be <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-siblings">

Answer (score 3):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="products/*[not(self::ARTNO)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ARTNO[1])"/>`, then use that in

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <Products>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Envelope/body/products/ARTNO"/>
            </Products>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ARTNO">
  <Product>
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('group', generate-id())"/>
  </Product>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That too seems to work correctly. I have read about the "Muenchian method",  and I get the general idea of it, but I would NEVER have been able to get it right, and although your example clearly works, I will have to spend some time figuring out HOW it works! Thanks!

Comment: @RichardRönnbäck this approach isn't really Muenchian grouping as such, but the essence here is that the key definition gives you a way to look up, given a particular `ARTNO`, all the other elements for which this is the nearest preceding `ARTNO`, i.e. all those between this `ARTNO` and the next (or the end of the `products` element if this is the last `ARTNO`).

Comment: It is not strictly Muenchian grouping although both approaches use a key. It simply keys non `ARTNO` elements by the generated id if the preceding `ARTNO` sibling, then processes all `ARTNO` elements and finds the following sibling with the key call.

Comment: Yes, I took some time to think through it, and once you figure it out it is not only clever, but actually quite straigh-forward. Again, thanks very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I post the entire working stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" name="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <Products>
                <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/body/products/*">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Products>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="products">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ARTNO"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ARTNO">
        <product>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="copy-siblings"/>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-siblings">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="copy-siblings"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ARTNO" mode="copy-siblings"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a self-taught developer I sometimes struggles a great deal to get my head around XSL, so let me ascertain that I have understood, somewhat, what is happening:

I do know that in XSL a more specific expression takes precedence, so I *think* that as nodes are processed, the template matching "ARTNO" without the mode simply copies the node, and then applies the templates with the mode "copy-siblings", the ARTNO template with the mode applied, effectively acts as an "exit", and the "*" takes care of the first instance of all other following siblings.

Is that somewhat correctly understood?

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: You've got the gist of it, though XSLT's [rules for what counts as a "more specific expression"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict) can sometimes trip you up.  Tests of `node()`, `text()`, `comment()`, `processing-instruction()`, `@*` or `*` have the lowest default precedence, then `prefix:*` or `@prefix:*` are next, then a specific element or attribute name test (`foo` or `@bar`).  Tests that involve more than one level of hierarchy (`foo/bar`, `*/*`, etc.) or any use of predicates (`foo[5]`, `*[@id]`, ...) will beat plain name tests.

Comment: ... but that's it - _any_ match that includes a `/` or `[]` is considered to have the same precedence, so neither `*[@id]` nor `foo/bar/baz/*/example[@kind = '3']/node()` is considered to be more specific than the other.

Comment: Indeed, but thanks to people like you, people like me progress :-)